# Securing Azure hosted Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

My use case is that a client will authenticate to my Api using a combination of secret fields (not user name and password), then be issued a token that will be passed in the headers of subsequent Api calls.

I've looked at Jwt which seem ideal and allow me to include authorization claims in the token. One of the benefits of Jwt is that they are stateless in that they don't need to be stored server side, the client simply presents the token which the server trusts and honours any claims - my issue here is with revoking the token. I'll need some form of server state to hold a list of users in case we need to revoke access, at that point would I be better storing the claims server side and staying away from Jwt? This [article](https://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=1388) suggests so.

Is there a stand out technology on Asp.Net core that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need revocation? As an alternative, what about short-lived access tokens paired with a refresh token?

Comment: How would that work in practice? Why it is beneficial to use refresh tokens?

Comment: It depends on the use case. Refresh tokens are typically used in this way: the server issues both an access token (with a short expiration, like 5-30 minutes) and a refresh token (with a long expiration, like 1-30 days). When the access token expires, the client must send the refresh token back to the server to get a new access token. This gives the server a chance to decide whether the client should still have access.